# Transferring a message between three pipes

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, pipe

I'm working on a project that sends a message between three processes: a parent with two children. The first process will take in the message and then send the message to a second process. The second process will read in a message and then transform it before sending it to the third process. The third process will read in a message and transform that message even more. Finally, the message will be sent back to the first process, printing it.

This is to be implemented using pipes and system calls in UNIX. I'm not that familiar with the process, so I'd appreciate any tips/advice you could provide. Below is my code. Thank you!

```
*#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ERR    (-1)             /* indicates an error condition */
#define READ   0                /* read end of a pipe */
#define WRITE  1                /* write end of a pipe */
#define STDIN  0                /* file descriptor of standard in */
#define STDOUT 1                /* file descriptor of standard out */
int main()
{
 int pid_1,               /* will be process id of first child, which inverts the string */
     pid_2;               /* will be process id of second child, which converts the string to uppercase */
 int fd[2]; //descriptor array for parent process
 int fd2[2]; //descriptor array for first child process
 int fd3[2]; //descriptor array for second child process
 char ch [100]; //original character array
 char ch2 [100]; //character array after reversal
 int index = 0; //size
 char character;
 while((character = getchar()) != '\n') //get input and put it into array
 {
    ch[index] = character;
    index++;
 }
 if(pipe (fd) == ERR)
 {
    perror("Parent pipe cannot be created\n");
    exit (ERR);
 }
 if (pipe (fd2) == ERR)              /* create a pipe  */
 {                                 /* must do before a fork */
     perror ("Pipe cannot be created.\n");
     exit (ERR);
 }
 if (pipe (fd3) == ERR)              /* create a pipe  */
 {                                 /* must do before a fork */
     perror ("Second pipe cannot be created.\n");
     exit (ERR);
 }
 if ((pid_1 = fork()) == ERR)        /* create 1st child   */
 {
     perror ("Second process cannot be created.\n");
     exit (ERR);
 }
 if (pid_1 != 0)                      /* in parent  */
 {
     close(fd2[0]); //close read end of first child
     close(fd[1]); //close write end of parent
     printf("Parent process sends message %s\n", ch);
     write(fd2[1], ch, sizeof(ch)); //write to write end of first child
     close(fd2[1]); //close write end of first child
     close(fd[0]);
     if ((pid_2 = fork ()) == ERR)     /* create 2nd child  */
     {
         perror ("Third process cannot be created.\n");
         exit (ERR);
     }
     if (pid_2 != 0)                   /* still in parent  */
     {
         wait ((int *) 0);           /* wait for children to die */
         wait ((int *) 0);
         read(fd[0], ch2, sizeof(ch2)); //read read end of parent process
         printf("Parent process receives message %s\n", ch2);
         int i = 0;
         while (i < index)
         {
             printf("%c", ch2[i]); //print message
             i++;
         }
         printf("\n");
         close(fd3[1]); //close write end of second child
         close(fd[0]); //close read end of parent process
     }
     else                                /* in 2nd child   */
     {
         close(fd3[1]); //close write end of second child
         close(fd2[0]); //close read end of first child
         read(fd3[0], ch2, sizeof(ch2)); //read read end of second child
         printf("Second child receives %s\n", ch2);
         int i = 0;
         while (i < index)
         {
             ch2[i] = toupper(ch2[i]); //convert to uppercase
             i ++;
         }
         printf("Second child sends message %s\n", ch2);
         write(fd[1],ch2, sizeof(ch2)); //write to write end of parent process
         close(fd3[0]); //close read end of second child
         close(fd[1]); //close read end of parent process
     }
 }
 else                                      /* in 1st child   */
 {
     close(fd2[1]); //close write end of first child
     close(fd[0]); //close read end of parent process
     read(fd2[0], ch, sizeof(ch)); //read read end of first child
     printf("First child receives message %s\n", ch);
     int i = 0;
     while (i < index)
     {
         ch2[i] = ch[index - 1 - i]; //reverse
         i++;
     }
     printf("First child sends message %s\n", ch2);
     write(fd3[1], ch2, sizeof(ch2)); //write to write end of second child
     close(fd3[1]); //close write end of second child
     close(fd2[0]); //close read end of first child
 }
 exit(0);
 }
```

Comment: Try something simpler first.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, and how to fix it. I tried following an example where it was just one child and one parent, and had that working, so I just added on another child. That's probably where I'm going wrong.

Comment: All right, you are attempting several things at once; which one fails? Is there an error message? Does the parent process receive a string from the user? Does the first child receive it through fd2? Does it reverse the string correctly? Does the second child receive the reversed string through fd3? Does it change the case correctly? Does the parent receive the uppercase string through fd? Can you isolate the thing that isn't working?

Comment: Did you forget to `pipe(fd3)`?

Comment: Unless this is homework, you're better off doing the piping using the shell, and write your C programs as simple stdin-to-stdout processors.

You can use mkfifo to help in creating a "loop" of processes.

Comment: @Beta: The code compiles. The parent process receives the string, the child receives it through fd2, it reverses this string, and that's when it breaks down.

Comment: @fork2execve: Homework assignment, so have to go about it this way

Comment: So you can simplify the problem. Remove the second child  entirely, and have the first child send the (reversed) string back to the parent via fd3. When that doesn't work, remove fd2 and fd and the user input and string reversal, and just have the child attempt to send "hello" to the parent through fd3. When that doesn't work, the answer will be staring at you: **you forgot to `pipe(fd3)`** (and `pipe(fd)` for that matter) and you're trying to send data through a pipe that doesn't exist. The ability to simplify code and isolate problems is a skill far more valuable than mere pipe-fitting.

Comment: @Beta: You were right in that I forgot to pipe the third process. The first child reverses the string correctly, the second child changes case correctly, but I am not sure if the parent receives the uppercase string. My debug message prints, but I get gibberish output. Did I miss a pipe somewhere? I edited the original code with my updated stuff.

Comment: @fork2execve: It's not even a graded assignment. We're currently creating a shell as a month-long project, and so this was just some exposure to system calls. But I understand where you're coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One should not write this much code without testing it. (There's a better way, which I'll get to in a moment.) But if you find yourself in this state, here's one way to track down a problem.

**Step 1:** Put in a few diagnostic output statement to verify that the code is doing what you intend and expect:

```
...
printf("Here\n");
read(fd3[0], ch2, sizeof(ch2)); //read read end of second child
close(fd3[0]); //close read end of second child
printf("second child receives %s\n", ch2);
...
printf("Input reversed\n");
printf("first child sends %s\n", ch2);
write(fd3[1], ch2, sizeof(ch2)); //write to write end of second child
...
```

This much is enough to show that something isn't working.

**Step 2:** simplify the code as much as possible without changing the misbehavior, until the bug has nowhere left to hide. In this case you will discover that **you are still neglecting to `pipe(fd3)`, even after I pointed that out to you and you acknowledged the problem and said you'd fixed it.** If that doesn't convince you of the importance of simplification, nothing ever will.

The correct way to write code is to build up slowly, testing at every step. You should have tested the fd3 link before attempting to hook it into a big circuit. Start with something small and simple, add complexity a little at a time, test new functionality in isolation and *never add to code that doesn't work.*

Comment: Parent process sends message Hi

    First child receives message Hi

    First child sends message 

    Second child receives message iH

    Second child sends message IH

    Parent process receives message gibberish (a square)

Comment: It's not letting me format correctly for some reason. Sorry.

Comment: @MatthewWeingarten: So ***simplify.*** The bug will leap out at you, you can fix it by moving one line. And it would be a good idea to lift most of that code out of `main()` and put it into functions like `firstChild(...)`, `secondChild(...)`, and `parent(...)`.

Comment: It seems to me that the bug lies between the transmission of the message from the second child back to the parent. That would mean I am not closing all the channels or closing too many, correct? Maybe I'm also closing them in the wrong place. All the things I try aren't changing the effect, however.

Comment: @MatthewWeingarten: Did you SIMPLIFY?? Why are you talking about "channels", plural, when you can eliminate all but one?

Comment: This is going to sound bad, but I don't know what I could to eliminate all but one. I apologize for my lack of knowledge in the area.

Comment: @MatthewWeingarten: Why apologize for not being an expert? Everyone who learns this stuff must start as a beginner, no exceptions. Have the second child send "hello" to the parent. Then you can eliminate the code that receives a message from the first child and the conversion to upper case. Then you can eliminate the first child altogether, along with `fd2` and `fd3`. That will reduce the length of the code quite a lot, and you'll see everything happening with `fd` very clearly.

Comment: I'm not quite following your logic here. I'm supposed to accomplish this task with three processes. Wouldn't I have only one if I were to remove fd2 and fd3 completely? And would that send "hello" statement come before the writing back of the message to the parent?

Comment: @MatthewWeingarten: The purpose of removing fd2 and fd3 is to clear away the clutter so that you can see what's going wrong. Once you see the bug you can go back to the full two-child three-pipe version and fix it. And I'm not sure I understand your second sentence-- I'm suggesting that the second child send "hello" through fd instead of the transformed string.

Comment: I was able to send "hello" over and see its correct output using a separate char array but cannot send ch2 over to get its output. What would that be indicating?

Comment: Totally agree with your advice to start small and build from there. ++ for tech support ;-)

Comment: Okay, got it fixed. The error was that I closed fd[0], as well as fd[1], prematurely. That was stupid, but a good learning experience. Thanks to all who helped!